# What is $E[X|Y]$ if the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, independence

Just looking for an explanation of how the conditional expectation "$E[X|Y]$" of any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ would change if we included the condition that $X$ and $Y$ be independent.

Normally:

- $E[X|Y] = \sum_xx(P_{X|A}(x|y))$ where $P$ stands for the PMF of $X|A$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, could we just apply the property of independent events

- $P(A|B) = P(A)$

to get that $E[X|Y] = \sum_x x\,P_X(x) = E[X]$?

Thank you!

Comment: $P(A|B)=P(A)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent. The formula you have above is for $P(A$ and $B)$.

Comment: @bburGsamohT Oh yes, my mistake. I will correct it!

Comment: The distribution of $X$ given $Y$, is the (unconditional) distribution of $X$. So the conditional mean, variance, and so on are the same as the unconditional mean, variance, and so on.

Comment: @AndréNicolas that's a very good way of articulating it. I've never worded it that way and it helps to hear it said that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E[X|Y]=E[X]$. In the case where $X$ and $Y$ are both discrete, you can relate this back to events through the identity $P(A|B)=P(A)$ for independent events $A,B$, where $P(B)>0$.

Comment: I guess my question lies in the "wording". Is saying $P(A|B) = P(A)$ the same as saying the PMF $P_{X|A}(x) = P_X(x)$? Thank you! It's obvious I don't yet have a good grasp of PMF's.

Comment: @DavidSouth You can take $A$ to be each event $X=x$ and take $B$ to be each event $Y=y$. Then $P(A|B)=P(A)$ becomes $p_{X|Y}(x|y)=p_X(x)$ in PMF notation.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. Thank you!